# Why my relation in laravel 5.8 not working?

Tags: laravel

Look at my codes and demo.

I have three tables `categories` and `knowledge_rooms` and `category_knowledge_room`. And all their data is stored.

[image: category]

categories table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name_fa');
        $table->string('name_en');
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->string('icon')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

knowledge_rooms table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('knowledge_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('lang');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('category_knowledge_room', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('knowledge_room_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['category_id', 'knowledge_room_id']);
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('knowledge_room_id')->references('id')->on('knowledge_rooms')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function register()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        $view->with('menus', Category::whereParent_id('0')->get());
    });
}
```

Category.php

```
public function knowledgeRooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(KnowledgeRoom::class);
}
```

master.blade.php

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    @foreach($menu->getChild as $submenu)
        @foreach($submenu->knowledgeRooms as $knowledgeRoom)
            {{ dd($knowledgeRoom) }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

web.php

```
Route::view('/', 'Home.master')->name('index');
```

But I see this demo, it is white page.

[image: blank page]

Comment: you will be having incorrect name casting for primary or foreign keys, see laravel doc for passing manual keys parameter in belongsToMany relations,.

Comment: What is the solution? Can you send me a sample here?

Comment: Firstly please confirm that does this relation gives data in tinker ? Like `Category::find(1)->knowledgeRooms;` does this work in tinker ?

Comment: Or what you have already done `Category::with('knowledgeRooms')->whereParent_id(0)->get()` have you tested it before passing to any view ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not work with `tinker `.

Comment: Okay let me make it more simple, in web.php just write a dummy route and inside that just return `Category::with('knowledgeRooms')->whereParent_id(0)->get();` and let me know what it gives.

Comment: that stuff belongs in the `boot` method of the Service Provider **not** the `register` method

Comment: I tested all your codes, but my problem did not solve yet.

Comment: I see in page blank and white..

Comment: No one can answer my question?

Comment: there is no way for us to know if that database query is actually returning any results ... we can only assume that you **think** it is supposed to return results ... are there records with `parent_id == 0`?  everything in the `register` method of that Service Provider belongs in the `boot` method